# Failed to decode JSON object when calling a GET request con Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, get

Intento enviar una solicitud GET luego de enviar un mensaje a un servidor, pero recibo un error. Creo que es porque

```
@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    try:
        user_message = request.form["text"]
        response = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond', data={"q":user_message})
        response = response.json()
        print("response :\n",response)
```

Aquí está el error Avíseme si necesita el rastreo completo.

```
2018-06-06 13:39:21+0100 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - 
[06/Jun/2018:12:39:21 +0000] "POST /conversations/default/respond HTTP/1.1" 500 11082 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"
2018-06-06 13:42:53+0100 [-] 2018-06-06 13:42:53 
ERROR    __main__  - Failed to decode json during respond request. 
Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Request content: 'b'q=Hi''
```

De verdad funciona bien con el terminal :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ curl -XPOST localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond -d '{"query":"Hello"}'
[{"recipient_id": "default", "text": "Hello! How can I help?"}]
```

#### Actualizacion

```
@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    try:
        user_message = request.values.get("text")
        response = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond', json={"key":user_message})
```

Da :

'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2018 14:28:30] "POST /chat HTTP/1.1" 200 -

**OS Version**
Linux 16.04
Flask                    1.0.2
Flask-MySQLdb            0.2.0
Flask-WTF                0.14.2

Comment: entiendo que escribes "Hi" en el formulario, ¿es así?

Comment: @fedorqui Si, de verdad, como [aqui](https://files.gitter.im/RasaHQ/rasa_core/9jS4/image.png)

Comment: Me parece que debes hacer `request.values.get('text')` en lugar de `request.form['text']`.

Comment: @fedorqui hmm .. Me da entonces `response :
 <Response [400]>
'Response' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @fedorqui Tenías razón, lo explicaré en una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como fedorqui ha notado hay que utilizar `request.values.get('text')` en lugar de `request.form['text']`

```
@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    try:
        user_message = request.values.get("text")
        response = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/conversations/default/respond', json={"query":user_message})
        response = response.json()
        print("response :\n",response) 
        response_text = response
        return jsonify(response[0])
```

Porque creo que es debido a la naturaleza del objeto de lo que devuelve la solicitud. De todos modos, [según user1807534](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279399/how-to-obtain-values-of-request-variables-using-python-and-flask/20341272#20341272) :

si quieres recuperar datos POST,

```
user_message = request.form.get("text")
```

si quieres recuperar datos GET (query string),

```
user_message = request.args.get("text")
```

O si no le importa / sabe si el valor está en la cadena de consulta o en los datos de la publicación,

```
user_message = request.values.get("text").
```

request.values es un CombinedMultiDict que combine Dicts from request.form y request.args.

**Sin embargo**, esto no lo hará aparecer en la aplicación Flask

Comment: Nótese que lo extraje de [How to obtain values of request variables using Python and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341272/1983854), donde explican que para POST se puede usar `request.form.get()`, para GET `request.args.get()` y si es indiferente `request.values.get()`.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Si super! ¿Sabes cómo hacerlo en la GUI? Creo que tengo que tocar la plantilla .html pero no estoy seguro. De todos modos intentaré cosas y, si es justo, vuelvo